# How does eclipse resolve a double-click on an error to a file?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT with a Makefile-based project.

When there is a compiler error in the Console window like

```
./foo/bar.h:207:5: error: blah blah
```

I double-click on it and it opens the file.  The problem is it opens the wrong copy of the file.  Our build system creates a secondary hard-linked `bar.h` in a build folder, and it opens that one instead of the original.  (FYI I have that secondary file marked as derived, but it was exhibiting the same behaviour before I did so.)

My question is how does Eclipse map such a double-clicked error to a file?  What paths does it search and in what order?  Is this configurable somewhere? The original is literally at `[project]/foo/bar.h` so I would like to configure it to open that file when I double-click on the above error, and not the derived hard-linked one at `build/wherever/foo/bar.h`.